# How do I override the spring framework version in Spring Batch?

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, dependency-management, spring-batch

I'm starting a new project with Spring Batch 2.1.6.RELEASE and I use Maven for depemdency management.

By default, it imports spring framework 2.5.6, but I'd like to use 3.0.5.RELEASE instead.

[This post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?p=344699#post344699) says it's compatible, but I don't know how to declare that in my maven pom file.

I tried just putting the dependencies for spring-core, spring-beans and spring-context versions 3.0.5.RELEASE, but that adds the libraries to the project without removing the 2.5.6 version.

I had a look at spring-batch-parent pom file, and there is a profile called "spring3" that uses the spring version I want. How do I activate a profile in my project's pom file ?

Thanks in advance,

Philippe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can exclude the transient dependency on Spring Framework v2.5.6 of Spring Batch by using the dependency [exclusions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#Dependency_Exclusions) element of the spring-batch dependency in maven. Something like...

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId> 
    </exclusion>
    <!-- Other exclusions here -->
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: That's a solution, but there must be a simpler one... they have those profiles for something... how can I force maven to use a profile declared in spring-batch's pom files ?

Comment: Incidently, adding the exclusions and then removing them made my dependency tree look ok with the correct versions. I don't know if this is some side-effect of using maven through Eclipse (STS)...

Comment: That's interesting, the profile in the spring-batch-parent sets a `spring.framework.version` property, which is used in dependencyManagement. Perhaps you could activate that profile during your build using `-P spring3` command line switch (easy to forget maybe) or perhaps you could define the `spring.framework.version` property for yourself in your project - not completely sure if this will work, worth a try though.

Comment: Actually I'm using maven through Spring Tool Suite (STS). I noticed an option to choose the profiles in the Project>Properties>Maven menu, but it does not affect the dependencies I see in my left pane... maybie it works at runtime though...